# VIM syntax high-lighting chokes in CSS files using data:image

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting

I have a CSS file with some pretty basic stuff including a data:image like so:

```
#next {
     background-image: url("data:image/png,%89PNG%0D%0");
```

The actual data string is much longer, but I've truncated for this post. The vim CSS syntax highlighter chokes on that long string and forces the rest of my css declarations in that file to not be highlighted. vim is also slow in this file when that declaration is visible (e.g. when it's trying to highlight for the data url). Anyone have any recommendations for fixing/circumventing this?

Comment: vim appears to do the right thing for me, so hard to find suggestions. have you got any weird extensions or plugins? try disabling those to start with.

Comment: Did you try the recently released Vim 7.3?

Comment: I've got the same issue, and tracked it down to the line `syntax on` in mi `.vimrc` file. So it's not caused by any plugin.

Answer (score 8):

I was just struggling with this issue.

For me the fix was to modify my .vimrc to include:

```
set synmaxcol=200
```

I got this tip from this thread: https://superuser.com/questions/302186/vim-scrolls-very-slow-when-a-line-is-to-long

Hope it helps someone else too.